# Sound issues in game speed J2ME

Tags: audio, java-me

When background sound is being played in game,the game speed is slightly low when compared to game without sound.. How to resolve this issue? The code which is been used for sound is as follows..

> menusound = Manager.createPlayer(inputstream, "audio/midi");
>       menusound.realize();
>       menusound.setLoopCount(-1);
>       menusound.start();

Comment: I have fiddled a lot with sound and music on the JavaME platform, and haven ever experienced a slowdown in framerate because of music playback. My guess is that your MIDI must be a rather complex one. Try with another MIDI file and see if it's still a problem.

Comment: You can find MIDI files optimized for JavaME at indiegamemusic.com
Optimized = All useless data and unsupported commands are stripped, and Standard Midi Format 0 (SMF0) is used rather than SMF1. Remember to select the "Optimized for JavaME" in your search.
Is it better when using one of those MIDI files?