# Midi sound file response is slower than wave sound file response

Tags: java-me

I'm using midi files for background sound in my game. I'm creating and playing sound as follow s:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                "/sound/" + bg.mid);
IngameSound = Manager.createPlayer(is, "audio/midi");
        IngameSound.setLoopCount(-1);
            IngameSound.start();
```

Using this code,the game play is slow. If wave sound file is used,then game play is fine.How to make game play smooth using midi files?

Comment: If MIDI playback is slower than WAV playback, then you must be using some really complex MIDI. Possibly one that uses a lot of commands that aren't even supported by the GM standard. (It can be a good idea to look for MIDI files that are specifically optimized for JavaME. Lots of those at IndieGameMusic.com). If you upload your MIDI somewhere, I can take a look at it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sound issues in game speed J2ME](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519242/sound-issues-in-game-speed-j2me)

Comment: Replacing midi file with other midi file improves game play speed,but not to that speed when played without sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sound performance via J2ME is often highly dependent on the device you are using, so what works well on one will often be nearly unusable on another.

However, one thing you can try to do is pre-load and/or prefetch all of your sounds prior to needing to play them (usually during the loading animation for a level), store all your players in an array and just tell them to start/stop/reset when you need to manipulate them. In the past I often found that the biggest performance hit with sound was the initial request to access a hardware resource, so anything you can do to perform all hardware requests as early as possible is usually beneficial.